# How to strip the string and replace the existing elements in DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a df as below:

```
Index  Site     Name
  0    Site_1   Tom
  1    Site_2   Tom
  2    Site_4   Jack
  3    Site_8   Rose
  5    Site_11  Marrie
  6    Site_12  Marrie
  7    Site_21  Jacob
  8    Site_34  Jacob
```

I would like to strip the 'Site_' and only leave the number in the "Site" column, as shown below:

```
Index   Site     Name
  0      1       Tom
  1      2       Tom
  2      4       Jack
  3      8       Rose
  5      11      Marrie
  6      12      Marrie
  7      21      Jacob
  8      34      Jacob
```

What is the best way to do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `pd.Series.str.extract`

This produces a copy with an updated columns

```
df.assign(Site=df.Site.str.extract('\D+(\d+)', expand=False))

      Site    Name
Index             
0        1     Tom
1        2     Tom
2        4    Jack
3        8    Rose
5       11  Marrie
6       12  Marrie
7       21   Jacob
8       34   Jacob
```

To persist the results, reassign to the data frame name

```
df = df.assign(Site=df.Site.str.extract('\D+(\d+)', expand=False))
```

---

### Using `pd.Series.str.split`

```
df.assign(Site=df.Site.str.split('_', 1).str[1])
```

### Alternative

Update instead of producing a copy

```
df.update(df.Site.str.extract('\D+(\d+)', expand=False))
# Or
# df.update(df.Site.str.split('_', 1).str[1])
df

      Site    Name
Index             
0        1     Tom
1        2     Tom
2        4    Jack
3        8    Rose
5       11  Marrie
6       12  Marrie
7       21   Jacob
8       34   Jacob
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best solution so far:)

Answer (score 0):

Make a array consist of the names you want. Then call 
yourarray = pd.DataFrame(yourpd, columns=yournamearray)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.apply()` to apply a function to each element in a series:

```
df['Site Name'] = df['Site Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
```

Comment: I tried similar code before. But the values doesn't change.

Comment: Reassign results to the column `df['Site Name'] = df['Site Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])`

Comment: @piRSquared ah I thought it was in place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just call replace on the column to replace all instances of "Site_":

```
df['Site'] = df['Site'].str.replace('Site_', '')
```

Comment: I got warning message as below:

Comment: Data_Extraction_Optimized_kdf_file.py:34: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  SiteInfo['Site'] = SiteInfo['Site'].str.replace('Site_', '')

Answer (score 0):

You can use exactly what you wanted (the `strip` method)

```
>>> df["Site"] = df.Site.str.strip("Site_")
```

Output

```
Index   Site     Name
  0      1       Tom
  1      2       Tom
  2      4       Jack
  3      8       Rose
  5      11      Marrie
  6      12      Marrie
  7      21      Jacob
  8      34      Jacob
```